# sql frequency of time instances

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to output the frequency of worker logins and hence I have two tables.

Table 1 : workers

```
+----------+
| workerid |
+----------+
| w1       |
| w2       |
| w3       |
| w4       |
+----------+
```

Table 2 : information

```
+----------+-----------+
| workerid | timestamp |
+----------+-----------+
| w1       |  23494944 |
| w1       |  24444444 |
| w3       |  26773735 |
| w4       |  86433333 |
+----------+-----------+
```

Expected output of query:

```
+------------------+----------------+
| count of workers | number_entries |
+------------------+----------------+
|                1 |              2 |
|                2 |              1 |
+------------------+----------------+
```

I wrote this but I am missing how to define the frequency of the time.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Worker_id)) as  count_of_workers, COUNT(FREQUENCY) as number_entries
GROUP BY user id
ORDER BY COUNT desc;
```

Comment: So one worker (#1) has 2 entries in table 2 and two workers have one entry eaxh in table 2. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want two `group by`s:

```
select num_entries, count(*) as num_workers
from (select worker_id, count(*) as num_entries
      from information
      group by worker_id
     ) i
group by num_entries
order by num_entries;
```